# MYSQL Result set differs when adding concatenation

Tags: mysql, concatenation, left-join, resultset, ifnull

I am trying to find a logical answer to an issue I'm having with two different results sets in MYSQL.

When I do concatenation on the list of table 3 fields into a single column, I get a different number of results.

I don't know if this matters, but tables 1&2 are the same table, just left joining with table 3 on different fields.

Below is a condensed version of my original query (1950 results):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       table1.invoice_num,
       table2.invoice_num,
       'ADMIN' as user_name,
       ...
       ...
       table3.invoice_type,
       table3.invoice_amount,
       table3.timestamp,
       table3.some_other_value_1,
       table3.some_other_value_2,
       table3.some_other_value_3,
       table3.some_other_value_4

FROM table3

LEFT JOIN table1
ON table1.value = table3.different_value
AND
...
...
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.value = table2.different_value
AND
;
```

Query after applying concatenation (1910 results):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       table1.invoice_num,
       table2.invoice_num,
       'ADMIN' as user_name,
       ...
       ...

       CONCAT(
         'Some text here ', IFNULL(table3.invoice_type, ''),
         'Some more text ', IFNULL(table3.invoice_amount, ''),
         'Text Text Text ', IFNULL(table3.timestamp,''),
         'Other value 1: ', IFNULL(table3.some_other_value_1,''),
         'Other value 2: ', IFNULL(table3.some_other_value_2,''),
         'Other value 3: ', IFNULL(table3.some_other_value_3,''),
         'Other value 4: ', IFNULL(table3.some_other_value_4,'')
         )

FROM table3

LEFT JOIN table1
ON table1.value = table3.different_value
AND
...
...
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.value = table2.different_value
AND
;
```

I know the IFNULL function is not causing the issue, because if I do the following I get the same number of results as the first query:

```
       IFNULL(table3.invoice_type,''),
       IFNULL(table3.invoice_amount,''),
       IFNULL(table3.timestamp,''),
       IFNULL(table3.some_other_value_1,''),
       IFNULL(table3.some_other_value_2,''),
       IFNULL(table3.some_other_value_3,''),
       IFNULL(table3.some_other_value_4,'')
```

I want to understand why I am getting less rows when concatenating. I would expect both result sets to have the same number of rows.

Comment: You've changed the columns being returned. That's going to impact the result set from the DISTINCT operation. And, IMHO, needing to use DISTINCT is often a code smell for a problem with how the query is written.

Comment: Short answer: ('a_', 'b') is distinct from ('a', '_b'); but the concatenations of those pairs are identical.